# Are intersection existence preserving functions between powersets of equinumouse infinite sets, injective images of some function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have two equinumerous infinite sets $A,B$; now if we say that $f$ is a bijection from $ \mathcal P(A)$ to $\mathcal P(B)$ that preserves existence of intersection; that is, we have: $$\forall x,y \in dom(f): x \cap y \neq \emptyset \iff f(x) \cap f(y) \neq \emptyset$$, does it allways follow that there must exist an injection $g: A \to B$, such that: $$\forall x \in \mathcal P(A): f(x)=\{g(m) \mid m \in x\} $$

Comment: I wouldn't say that $f$ preserves intersection in your case, just *disjointness*.

Comment: I thought its the same. I've edited it.

Comment: You're just rewriting the same condition (applying negation on both side of an equivalence). To preserve intersection would be $f(x\cap y)=f(x)\cap f(y)$.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: Ok then I'll call it preserving "existence" of intersections.

Comment: I still have no idea what was wrong with "preserving disjointness", since it is *exactly* what you are assuming.

Comment: I wonder what we can say about $f(\{x\})$. To start we might note that $x\in y$ if and only if $\{x\}\cap y\ne\emptyset$...

Comment: @AsafKaragila, no problem at all, I just like matters to be phrased in terms of existence of intersections, which turns to be the same as presering disjointness. I just want the phrasing to be more positive of intersections that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is yes, and the function $g$ is actually a bijection. To prove it, first observe that the hypothesis on $f$ imply the following facts:

(1) $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$

(2) For each $x \in A$, $f(\{x\})$ is a singleton (that is, there exists $y \in B$ such that $f(\{x\}) = \{y\}$).

(3) For each $y \in B$, $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is also a singleton.

To prove (1), let $Y = f(\emptyset)$. If $b \in Y$ then $\{b\} \cap Y \ne \emptyset$, so   $f^{-1}(\{b\}) \cap f^{-1}(Y) \ne \emptyset$. But $f^{-1}(Y) = \emptyset$,  a contradiction.

To prove (2), let $S_x = f(\{x\})$. By (1) and the fact that $f$ is a bijection we have $S_x \ne \emptyset$. Now suppose $\{a,b\} \subset S_x$,  $a \ne b$. Then $\{a\} \cap\{b\} = \emptyset$, so $f^{-1}(\{a\}) \cap f^{-1}(\{b\}) = \emptyset$. In particular, $x$ cannot belong to both sets, so either $\{x\} \cap f^{-1}(\{a\}) = \emptyset$ or $\{x\} \cap f^{-1}(\{b\}) = \emptyset$. But that would imply either $S_x\cap\{a\} = \emptyset$ or $S_x\cap\{b\} = \emptyset$, a contradiction. Hence $S_x$ has exactly one element.

To prove (3), let $y \in B$ and suppose $\{a,b\} \subset f^{-1}(\{y\})$, $a \ne b$ (notice that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ cannot be empty). By (2), both $f(\{a\})$ and $f(\{b\})$ are singletons, and since $f$ is a bijection, at least one of them, say $f(\{a\})$, must be different from $\{y\}$. But this is not possible because then we would have $\{a\} \cap f^{-1}(\{y\}) \ne \emptyset $ but $f(\{a\}) \cap \{y\} = \emptyset$

Now define $g: A \longrightarrow B$ by the condition $g(x) = y \iff y \in f(\{x\})$ (that is, $g(x)$ is the one element in $f(\{x\})$). To prove that the function $g$ satisfies the required condition, let $X \in  \mathcal P(A)$ be given. Then we have:

(a) If $b \in f(X)$, then $\{b\} \cap f(X) \ne \emptyset$, so $f^{-1}(\{b\}) \cap X \ne \emptyset$. By (3), $f^{-1}(\{b\}) = \{a\}$ for some $a \in A$, so it follows that $a \in X$ and $g(a) = b$, so $b \in \{g(m) \mid m \in X\}$. Hence $f(X) \subset \{g(m) \mid m \in X\}$

(b) Conversely, if $b \in \{g(m) \mid m \in X\}$, then $b = g(a)$ for some $a \in X$. Then $\{a\} \cap X \ne \emptyset$ and, by definition of $g$, $f(\{a\}) = \{b\}$, which implies $\{b\} \cap f(X) = f(\{a\}) \cap f(X) \ne \emptyset$. Hence $b \in f(X)$, so $\{g(m) \mid m \in X\} \subset f(X)$